# Displaying graphics for only one slide in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics, overlays

I got a question regarding the beamer class.

What I want to achieve is a list of items, that are uncovered one by one, interrupted by a graphic that covers the whole text area.
The graphic should only be displayed for one single slide, between Item 1.2 and Item 1.3. 
I only get it to be put inside the itemize environment. How can I escape the environment for only one slide, and continue with the items afterwards?

My MWE so far:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{PaloAlto}
\usecolortheme{seagull}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame1}
\begin{itemize}
 \item<+-> Item1
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<+-> Item 1.1
        \item<+-> Item 1.2    
        \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{\textheight}<+>
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \end{overlayarea}
        \item<+-> 1.3
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `\againframe` to smuggle an additional frame in between your overlays, on which you can display your image in full size:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{PaloAlto}
\usecolortheme{seagull}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}<1-3>[label=foo]
\frametitle{Frame1}
\begin{itemize}
 \item<+-> Item1
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<+-> Item 1.1
        \item<+-> Item 1.2    
        \item<+-> 1.3
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\end{frame}

\againframe<4->{foo}

\end{document}
```