# Beamer : Include slides between multiple overlays.

Tags: beamer, overlays

I am creating the overlay effect for the Outline of my presentation using the following code.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\frametitle{Overlays}
\onslide<1->{First Line of Text}
\onslide<2->{Second Line of Text}  
\onslide<3->{Third Line of Text}

\end{frame}

\end{document
```

This gives me 3 slides each having the appropriate text highlighted. How can i include another slide after the first overlay slide ? This slide will explain the topic highlighted, then again next slide should be 2nd overlay slide with 2nd topic highlighted and so on.

Comment: have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/454357/displaying-graphics-for-only-one-slide-in-beamer

Comment: @samcarter  sorry I am new to latex. Could you explain me a bit more ? For ex If i have another frame containing text, where should I write `\againframe` command ? I think I cannot call it after `\onslide<1->{First Line of Text}`

Comment: I added an example below. Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your desired output can be achieved by using [Displaying graphics for only one slide in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/454357/displaying-graphics-for-only-one-slide-in-beamer)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}<1>[label=foo]
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\frametitle{Overlays}
\onslide<1->{First Line of Text}

\onslide<2->{Second Line of Text}  

\onslide<3->{Third Line of Text}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
frame with some other text or images explaining something
\end{frame}

\againframe<2>{foo}

\begin{frame}
one more frame
\end{frame}

\againframe<3>{foo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what i required.

Comment: @SiddhantTandon You're welcome!